# How to use abstract class' child type as the type of an abstract method's parameter?

Tags: java, types, abstract-class

Let's say there're 2 classes:

- `Foo` (an *abstract* class)
- `Bar` (a child of Foo)

I want the type of an parameter of an abstract function of `Foo` to match the type of the child class that implements `Foo` (such a class could be `Bar`).

I thought I could use the constrained generic types, but I have no idea how to constrain the type to match the child class.

Example:

```
abstract class Foo {
    public abstract boolean testSth( [Type of the child] obj );
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    public boolean testSth( Bar obj ) { // I need the parameter to be of type Bar
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the generic to whatever extends `Foo`.

Comment: Well, you can use `abstract class Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`... that's what enums do. It's not a guarantee of sanity, but it's at least a start. Then `Bar` will extend `Foo<Bar>`.

Comment: Why not simply declare your method without generic type and use `Foo` like `testSmth(Foo obj)`? It is certain that you will not be able to pass instance of abstract `Foo` class since we can't create instance of such class. We can only create instances of non-abstract classes so you are sure that it will be instance of `Bar` or some other non-abstract class extending at some point `Foo`.

Comment: @Pshemo: The point is that `Bar.testSth` will only be able to handle a `Bar`, not a `Baz` or some other derived type. It's not an uncommon situation.

Comment: @AndrewLi But if there would be another class – say `Baz` – that would also extend from `Foo`, then `testSth` would accept an `Baz` instance as well as `Bar` instance, or am I missing something?

Comment: @JonSkeet True, but since question doesn't really contain any use-case it is worth asking about simplest solution before introducing self bounded generic types.

Comment: @Pshemo: It's not the simplest solution to the question asked though - the OP wants to restrict calls to `Foo.Bar` to ones passing in a `Bar` as an argument. Your comment doesn't suggest a solution to that. The statement after the bulleted list makes it pretty clear what the OP is after, IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet After rereading question I see what you mean. I was too focused on title and missed most important fact that OP wants to ensure that method in child class will also accept only *that* child objects. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously,  just pass the child type as generic type to parent class:

```
abstract class Foo<T> {
   // or Foo<T extends Foo<T>>
   public abstract boolean testSth(T obj );
}

class Bar extends Foo<Bar> {
    @Override
     public boolean testSth( Bar obj ) { // I need the parameter to be of type Bar
       // ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: You might want `T extends Foo<T>`

Comment: I've actually tried to avoid this very approach that uses redundant definition of the class type, but I guess Java doesn't provide any construct to reference the child type in method parameter, so this solution is (unfortunately) the only one available.