# Abstract method is not considered implemented when using Child class as return types

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have the classes

```java
abstract class A<T> {

    public abstract A<T> someFunction(A<?> obj);
}

public class B extends A<Integer>{

    public B someFunction(B obj){...}
}
```

I get an error that says `Class B must be declared abstract or must implement the abstract method someFunction(A<?> obj) in A`. My return type and parameter type are children of A. I don't understand why I am still getting this error.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40072186/how-to-use-abstract-class-child-type-as-the-type-of-an-abstract-methods-parame) is one solution I see where I can change `A` to something like `A<T, ChildName>` and use `ChildName` as the abstract function's parameter type. Is there a different way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is okay for `B.someFunction()` to return a class more derived than `A.someFunction()`. It is still the same method, and the override works.

However, it is not okay for `B.someFunction()` to ***accept a parameter*** of a class more derived than `A.someFunction()`.  When you try to do that, the override breaks.

Think of it this way: someone may have a reference to an `A` which is in fact an instance of `B`.  They may invoke it passing it an actual `A`. However, `B.someFunction()` expects an instance of `B`, and it will try to invoke methods of `B` which do not exist in the `A` that was passed. That would not work.